# Single instance EC2 env versus multiple split stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, architecture

I am fairly new to AWS and have designed a fairly flexible architecture which is fairly performant and fault tolerant over multiple regions/AZs

However I was thinking - what would the main disadvantages of sticking my entire stack (apps, DB, etc) onto one or two huge machines (r3.4x/8xlarge) or similar and then simply creating an AMI snapshot in S3 every x minutes and moving it cross-region to cover DR/HA

The performance of these machines (with provisioned IOPS/10 GbE) should be far in excess of my application scalability requirements for at least 3 years!

Comment: Well, if the instance goes down, there goes your stack. The phrase "putting all your eggs in one basket" comes to mind...

Comment: I could keep a fail over instance running behind ELB though?

Comment: You could yes. This highly depends on your workload and what you want to accomplish, thus your question isn't really answerable here. The beauty of AWS is that you can test, test, and test some more with different configurations before committing.